# Installing R from R project repo (Debian 10): key issue

Tags: debian, repository, r

I wanted to install R from the R Project repository on Debian 10. The following packages are required:

```
sudo apt install dirmngr -- install-recommends
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg2
```

Then, if I follow e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-debian-10 and do

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.WVA4wGygKd/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution to this is to use an alternative keyserver, such as `keyserver.ubuntu.com`:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
```

and then to add the relevant repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/'
```

However, `sudo apt update` leads to the following error:

```
Err:4 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B8F25A8A73EACF41
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B8F25A8A73EACF41
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

This means that this key as to be added with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B8F25A8A73EACF41
```

Then the installation can be simply carried on using e.g.

```
sudo apt install r-base-core r-base-dev
```

I hope it will be useful for users encountering similar problems.